# passing double pointers as 2d arrays in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

In my code, I am passing a double pointer to an integer as a representation of a 2D array but get segfaults - this problem gets fixed (oddly enough) when I pass the array as an array (with brackets instead)

This is the main function:

```
int main(void) {
    int matrix[3][3] = {
        { 0, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 0 }
    };
    printf("matrix first value outside func %d", matrix[0][0]);
    CSR *csr_val = convert_to_csr(matrix, 3, 3);
    output(csr_val, stdout, 1);
}
```

and this is the beginning of the function `convert_to_csr`:

```
CSR *convert_to_csr(int **matrix, size_t row_len, size_t col_len) {
    printf("first value of array %d", **matrix);
```

this essentially makes a seg fault when I run it but when I use the matrix form (ie `matrix[][3]`) it works fine. Does this have anything to do with the fact that this matrix isn't dynamically allocated and is rather allocated on the stack?

How would I go about implementing this if I cant guarantee the size of matrix at compile time though?

Listed above what I tried and what worked.

Answer (score 3):

> does this have anything to do with the fact that this matrix isn't
> dynamically allocated and is rather allocated on the stack?

The array declared like

```
int matrix[3][3] = {
    {0, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 1},
    {0, 1, 0}
};
```

used as an argument expression in a call of the function `convert_to_csr` in turn declared like

```
CSR* convert_to_csr(int **matrix, size_t row_len, size_t col_len);
```

is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element of the type `int ( * )[3]`. But the corresponding function parameter has type `int **` and these pointer types are not compatible.

Pay attention to that you could allocate the array dynamically like

```
int ( *matrix )[3] = malloc( sizeof( int[3][3] ) );
```

but you would have the same problem with the incompatibility of pointer types.

If your compiler supports variable length arrays then you can declare the function like

```
CSR* convert_to_csr( size_t row_len, size_t col_len, int matrix[row_len][col_len] );
```

and pass to the function arrays with different values of `row_len` and `col_len`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a type mismatch that causes undefined behavior, which explains why you get segmentation faults:

When you pass `matrix` to `convert_to_csr` declared as `CSR *convert_to_csr(int **matrix, size_t row_len, size_t col_len)`:

- the type of the argument is `int[3][3]` (array of 3 arrays of 3 `int`), which gets passed as a pointer to the first row, ie: `int (*)[3]` (pointer to arrays of 3 `int`)
- the expected argument type is `int **` (pointer to pointers to `int`) which is a different and incompatible type.

A pointer to arrays of 3 `int` is not the same as a pointer to `int *`. You should indeed modify the prototype of `convert_to_csr` and specify a type compatible with that of `matrix`.

If the dimensions are known at compile time, the prototype should be:

```
CSR *convert_to_csr(int matrix[][3], size_t row_len, size_t col_len)
```

and passing the `col_len` is redundant.

If your compiler supports VLAs (*variable length arrays*, a C99 feature allowing arrays to have dimensions specified as runtime values)<sup>1</sup>, you could specify the number of columns in the prototype, but you must change the order of the arguments:

```
CSR *convert_to_csr(size_t row_len, size_t col_len, int matrix[][col_len])
```

Note that the matrix with dimensions computed at runtime can be defined at the local scope with automatic storage (aka *on the stack*) this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
[...]

CSR *convert_to_csr(size_t row_len, size_t col_len, int matrix[][col_len]) {
    printf("first value of array %d\n", matrix[0][0]);
    printf("first value of array %d\n", **matrix);      // totally equivalent
}

int main(void) {
    size_t cols = get_column_number();
    size_t rows = get_row_number();
    int matrix[rows][cols];  // cannot have an initializer, hope it fits
    for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < rows; c++) {
            matrix[r][c] = get_matrix_value(r, c);
        }
    }
    [...]
    printf("Matrix first value outside func: %d\n", matrix[0][0]);

    // Passing the matrix as a void pointer
    convert_to_csr(3, 3, matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

And the same matrix could also be allocated from the heap:

```
    int (*matrix)[cols] = calloc(sizeof(*matrix), rows); // initialized to 0
```

`matrix` is then a pointer that can be passed to `convert_to_csr` the same way and the memory it points to can be freed with

```
    free(matrix);
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I just realized there's a mistake in my answer(fixed already).

It should be "a **static** array (whatever how many dimensions it is) in C is stored contiguously in memory".

So this means the compiler will treat the 2D array `matrix[3][3]` as a 1D array if you don't explicitly tell the compiler to treat it like a 2D one. I know it's confusing, but please run the following code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int matrix[3][3] = {
        {0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 1},
        {0, 1, 0}
    };
   
    int **ptr1 = matrix;
    int (*ptr2)[3] = matrix;
    printf("ptr1: %p\n", ptr1);
    printf("ptr2: %p\n", ptr2);
    printf("*ptr1: %p\n", *ptr1);
    printf("*ptr2: %p\n", *ptr2);
    return 0;
}
```

You can get the output like:

```
ptr1: 0x7ffe5261a090
ptr2: 0x7ffe5261a090
*ptr1: 0x100000000
*ptr2: 0x7ffe5261a090
```

Your `ptr1`, `ptr2`,and `*ptr2` might be different than mine (as we run on different machine) but the third line `*ptr1: 0x100000000` should be the same and it doesn't looks like an actual address at all.

This is what I mean by "the compiler treat it like a 1D array if you don't tell it". So when you dereference `ptr1` using `*ptr1`, you're treating the value at `matrix[0][0]` as a pointer (since `ptr1` is an `int**`). This is why you get a strange and seemingly unrelated memory address, like `0x100000000`. It's interpreting the integer value at `matrix[0][0]` (which is `0`) as a memory address, leading to a sig fault.

Please notice that operation like `int **ptr1 = matrix;` is actually problematic and should not compile without a warning or error in standard C. `ptr1` is a pointer to a pointer to an int, but `matrix` is a 2D array (specifically, an array of arrays of int). In C, these are not compatible types, as the memory layout they expect is different. If your compiler allows this assignment, it's doing so without proper type checking, which is unsafe.

Comment: and yeah`int ** arr` is typically used for a **dynamically** allocated 2D array (`malloc()`) where each row is an independently allocated array of integers, and `arr` points to an array of pointers, each pointing to one of these rows.

Comment: The comment _"`int ** arr` is typically used for a dynamically allocated 2D array..."_ is wrong. What you describe is a jagged array with the problem that the storage is not contiguous and so not an array; this is sometimes called a _simulated_ 2D array. This is handy for strings, but it has cache locality problems when used as an array. Commonly 2D dynamic arrays use VLA pointers, or sometimes a 2D array is simulated by a 1D dynamic array with indices calculated from row and column offsets.